# Fisher Information Matrix of Matrix Variate F Distribution

Tags: expected-value, fisher-information, matrix-calculus, matrix-variate-distribution

Let $\mathbf{X}$ follow a matrix variate F distribution with pdf
$$
\begin{align}
f\left(\mathbf{X} | \mathbf{\Sigma}, n, \nu\right) =  \frac{\Gamma_p(\frac{n + \nu }{2})}{\Gamma_p(\frac{n}{2})\Gamma_p(\frac{\nu}{2})} |\mathbf{\Sigma}|^{\frac{\nu}{2}} |\mathbf{X}|^{\frac{n - p - 1}{2}} |\mathbf{\Sigma}+ \mathbf{X}|^{-\frac{n + \nu}{2}},
\end{align}
$$
where $\mathbf{X}$ is the symmetric positive definite data matrix, $\mathbf{\Sigma}$ is the sym p.d. scale matrix and $n$ and $\nu$ are scalar parameters.

I am just interested in the Fisher Information Matrix w.r.t. the scale matrix $\mathbf{\Sigma}$.

Now
$$
\begin{align}
d \log(f\left(\mathbf{X} | \mathbf{\Sigma}, n, \nu\right)) 
&= \frac{\nu}{2} d \log|\mathbf{\Sigma}| - \frac{n + \nu}{2} d \log |\mathbf{\Sigma}+ \mathbf{X}| \\
&= \frac{\nu}{2} tr( \mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1} d \mathbf{\Sigma}) - \frac{n + \nu}{2} tr((\mathbf{\Sigma}+ \mathbf{X})^{-1}d\mathbf{\Sigma}),
\end{align}
$$
such that
$$
\begin{align}
d^2 \log(f\left(\mathbf{X} | \mathbf{\Sigma}, n, \nu\right)) 
&= \frac{\nu}{2} d tr( \mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1} d \mathbf{\Sigma}) - \frac{n + \nu}{2} d tr((\mathbf{\Sigma}+ \mathbf{X})^{-1}d\mathbf{\Sigma})\\
&= - \frac{\nu}{2} tr( \mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1} d \mathbf{\Sigma}\mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1} d \mathbf{\Sigma}) + \frac{n + \nu}{2} tr((\mathbf{\Sigma}+ \mathbf{X})^{-1} d\mathbf{\Sigma}(\mathbf{\Sigma}+ \mathbf{X})^{-1} d\mathbf{\Sigma})\\
\end{align}
$$
so the Hessian of the log-likelihood obtains as,
$$
\frac{\partial^2 \log(f\left(\mathbf{X} | \mathbf{\Sigma}, n, \nu\right))}{\partial vech(\mathbf{\Sigma}) \partial vech(\mathbf{\Sigma})^{\top} } = \mathbf{D}^{\top} \left( - \frac{\nu}{2} ( \mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1} \otimes \mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1} ) + \frac{n + \nu}{2} ((\mathbf{\Sigma}+ \mathbf{X})^{-1} \otimes (\mathbf{\Sigma}+ \mathbf{X})^{-1}  ) \right) \mathbf{D},
$$
where $\mathbf{D}$ is the duplication matrix.

Now to get to the Fisher Information matrix w.r.t. $\mathbf{\mathbf{\Sigma}}$ I need the expectation $\mathbf{E}\left((\mathbf{\Sigma}+ \mathbf{X})^{-1} \otimes (\mathbf{\Sigma}+ \mathbf{X})^{-1}\right)$ or alternatively
$\mathbf{E}\left(tr((\mathbf{\Sigma}+ \mathbf{X})^{-1} d\mathbf{\Sigma}(\mathbf{\Sigma}+ \mathbf{X})^{-1} d\mathbf{\Sigma})\right)$

Unfortunately I couldn't find these expectations to have been derived anywhere in the literature. I tried to derive the distribution of $(\mathbf{\Sigma}+ \mathbf{X})^{-1}$, but it does not seem to be a well known one. I tried to compute the second expectation mentioned above via the usual formula as follows (ignoring the normalizing constant).
$$
\begin{align}
&\int_{\mathbf{X} > 0} tr((\mathbf{\Sigma}+ \mathbf{X})^{-1} d\mathbf{\Sigma}(\mathbf{\Sigma}+ \mathbf{X})^{-1} d\mathbf{\Sigma}) |\mathbf{X}|^{\frac{n-p-1}{2}} |\mathbf{\Sigma}+ \mathbf{X}|^{-\frac{n + \nu}{2}} d \mathbf{X} \\
=&\int_{\mathbf{X} > 0} tr((\mathbf{\Sigma}+ \mathbf{X})^{-1} d\mathbf{\Sigma}(\mathbf{\Sigma}+ \mathbf{X})^{-1} d\mathbf{\Sigma}) |\mathbf{X}|^{\frac{n}{2}} |\mathbf{\Sigma}+ \mathbf{X}|^{-\frac{n + \nu}{2}} d \left(\frac{\mathbf{X}}{|\mathbf{X}|^{\frac{p+1}{2}}} \right),
\end{align}
$$
now it is well known that the measure $\left(\frac{\mathbf{X}}{|\mathbf{X}|^{\frac{p+1}{2}}} \right)$ is invariant to the transformation $\mathbf{X} \rightarrow \mathbf{\Sigma}^{1/2} \mathbf{X} \mathbf{\Sigma}^{1/2}$, so that we can simplify the integral to
\begin{align}
& |\mathbf{\Sigma}|^{-\frac{\nu}{2}} \int_{\mathbf{X} > 0} tr( (\mathbf{I} + \mathbf{X})^{-1} \mathbf{\Sigma}^{1/2} d\mathbf{\Sigma}\mathbf{\Sigma}^{1/2} (\mathbf{I} + \mathbf{X})^{-1} \mathbf{\Sigma}^{1/2} d\mathbf{\Sigma}\mathbf{\Sigma}^{1/2}) |\mathbf{X}|^{\frac{n}{2}} |\mathbf{I} + \mathbf{X}|^{-\frac{n + \nu}{2}} d \left(\frac{\mathbf{X}}{|\mathbf{X}|^{\frac{p+1}{2}}} \right) \\
=& |\mathbf{\Sigma}|^{-\frac{\nu}{2}} \int_{\mathbf{X} > 0} tr( (\mathbf{I} + \mathbf{X})^{-1} \mathbf{\Sigma}^{1/2} d\mathbf{\Sigma}\mathbf{\Sigma}^{1/2} (\mathbf{I} + \mathbf{X})^{-1} \mathbf{\Sigma}^{1/2} d\mathbf{\Sigma}\mathbf{\Sigma}^{1/2}) |\mathbf{X}|^{\frac{n-p-1}{2}} |\mathbf{I} + \mathbf{X}|^{-\frac{n + \nu}{2}} d \mathbf{X},
\end{align}
which means that all I need to get to the solution is to solve this integral:
$$
\int_{\mathbf{X} > 0} tr( (\mathbf{I} + \mathbf{X})^{-1} \mathbf{A} (\mathbf{I} + \mathbf{X})^{-1} \mathbf{A}) |\mathbf{X}|^{\frac{n-p-1}{2}} |\mathbf{I} + \mathbf{X}|^{-\frac{n + \nu}{2}} d \mathbf{X},
$$
where $\mathbf{A}$ is just some arbitrary matrix. Here I am stuck again.

Any help would be much appreciated.